# Suppose that a training set contains only a single example, repeated 100 times. What will a back propagation network predict for this example?

Tags: backpropagation

Suppose that a training set contains only a single example, repeated 100 times. In 80 of the 100 cases, the single output value is 1; in the other 20, it is 0. What will a back propagation network predict for this example, assuming that it has been trained and reaches a global optimum? (Hint: to find the global optimum, differentiate the error function and set it to zero.)